# Intenational Credit card

Tags: credit-card

How to get an inernational credit card? I can't get it in my country from a normal bank I need a card from a virtual bank or sth like that . what is the best way.

Comment: what country would that be?

Comment: Also, what specifically are you looking for to make it "international"?  Visa/Mastercard's networks are global; a card from a local bank using either of them should work in most of the world.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of that would make the card "international", beyond it being on an internationally supported network (many are on several of these), is the presence of a chip -- which most US cards are still missing.

Talk to your bank and ask if they have a chip-and-PIN or chip-and-signature card available. If they don't, try other banks; a bit of websearching will help you find the major ones which do offer chip cards, but they may also be available from smaller banks and credit unions which don't get onto those lists.

Of course you still have to qualify for the credit card. And the rates/fees/bonuses may or may not be different for the chip card versus stripe-only, or for the same card from different banks; shop around.

I don't think there's much we can say beyond that which won't become outdated too quickly to be worth posting.